# Is it possible to create an anonymous class associated with a specific class/package name?

Tags: java

If I'm running in Class X, then all anonymous classes are associated with X$#, in some way.

Is there a way when creating/declaring an anonymous class to have it associated explicitly with a specific package+class?

Comment: I'm curious - what's the use-case for this?

Comment: partially just curious, but somewhat in terms of organization/grouping of anonymous classes throughout a project.

Comment: Would this then mean that this class is no longer anonymous, as it would have a name?

Comment: "to have it associated explicitly with a specific package+class" yes, declare it in that specific class/package.

Comment: In other words, you cannot. Since the anonymous class has no visible name, it has  to have an internal name for the compiler to handle it. You do not have control over the latter.  So, use named classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Move your anonymous class definition code to nested (static) classes inside the class. If you are capturing local variables, then pass them in a constructor.